# How do you get the current solution directory from a Editor Classifier Project (c#)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility

From an add-in, we can obtain the solution path using following way.

```
_applicationObject = (DTE2)application;  // retrieved from OnConnection method
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
```

How would you do this via a **Editor Classifier Project** (Visual C# --> Extensibility--> Editor Classifier)?

I am unable to get the DTE object either from application or using the getService method.

Could someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

```
 internal class TestQuickInfoSource : IQuickInfoSource
    {
        private TestQuickInfoSourceProvider m_provider;
        private ITextBuffer m_subjectBuffer;
        private Dictionary<string, string> m_dictionary;
        private bool m_isDisposed;
        private DTE2 _applicationObject;

        [Import]
        internal SVsServiceProvider ServiceProvider = null;

        //constructor that initializes the dictionary
        public TestQuickInfoSource(TestQuickInfoSourceProvider provider, ITextBuffer subjectBuffer)
        {
            m_provider = provider;
            m_subjectBuffer = subjectBuffer;

              **// HERE the dictionary with the tool-tip info is created. I would need the solution path here ideally so that I can dynamically create the dictionary from a file there. Following commented statements.**

            // Get an instance of the currently running Visual Studio IDE
            //DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
            //string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);

            //DTE dte = (DTE)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

            //string solutionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);

            //_applicationObject = (DTE2)provider;

            //string solutionPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);            


            //string gg = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ToString();

            //string solutionDirectory = ((EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime
            //                                  .InteropServices
            //                                  .Marshal
            //                                  .GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0"))
            //                       .Solution
            //                       .FullName;



            //EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
            //string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);

            //_applicationObject = (DTE2)dte;

            //string solutionDir1 = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);


            string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

            //EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));
            //System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);

            //Reading Resource File
            //string path = "";



            //EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
            //dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.10.0");

            //_applicationObject = (DTE2)dte2;

            //if (_applicationObject.ActiveDocument != null)
            //{
           //    string y = _applicationObject.ActiveDocument.ToString();
            //    string solutionPat = Path.GetDirectoryName(dte2.Solution.FullName);                
            //}

            //Connect objConnect = new Connect();
            //Array objArray = null;
            //objConnect.OnConnection(dte2, ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_AfterStartup, null, ref objArray);


            //these are the method names and their descriptions
            m_dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            m_dictionary.Add("add", "int add(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nAdds one integer to another.");
            m_dictionary.Add("subtract", "int subtract(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nSubtracts one integer from another.");
            m_dictionary.Add("multiply", "int multiply(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nMultiplies one integer by another.");
            m_dictionary.Add("divide", "int divide(int firstInt, int secondInt)\nDivides one integer by another.");
            m_dictionary.Add("#include", "Custom Tool-Tip !");
        }
```

Please check the comments in bold to understand the problem

Comment: Could you show the code that you have already tried?

Comment: And maybe you should add the tag [vs-extensibility] and/or [visual-studio-extensions] to your question

Comment: Please check the comments in bold to understand the issue

Answer (score 3):

You could use `GetGlobalService`, as such:

```
var dte2 = (DTE2)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(SDTE));
```

but the way you usually do it, is given by @Srikanth Venugopalan. If you get "NULL", there's something wrong, and without knowing more, it's hard to help.

Comment: It's cool but buggy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209589/project-names-in-visual-studio-solution-sometimes-are-empty

Answer (score 0):

You can try importing [SVsServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.svsserviceprovider.aspx) and get instance using the `GetService` method

[This walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834473.aspx) gives you an illustration on how to obtain a reference to the `DTE` object.

Once you have the `DTE` reference, the rest should be similar to what you would do in the add-n.